# Working in vi editor on ec2 server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, vi

Can you please help me using vi editor for programming

1. How to close the window, saving the content of opened page. // I use Esc wq: but it keep open the window
2. Deleting selected content
3. going to direct line // Esq /. any other way
4. Opening new file in same window without closing older one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to close the window, saving the content of opened page. // I use Esc wq: but it keep open the window

```
 ESC + :wq
```

> Deleting selected content

how do you select content in VI ? to delete a line, press `dd`. To delete 2 lines, press `2dd`... so on and so forth

> going to direct line // Esq /. any other way

```
ESC + :120
```

above combination will take you to line no. 120. OR run below command:

```
vi +120 file_name
```

> Opening new file in same window without closing older one

```
ESC + :split new_file_name
```

sorry for the formatting of this post.

Comment: deleting file I could not understand

Comment: Deleting file? I did not mention anything with respect to deleting file. I think you want to know how to delete lines.

Comment: yes I mean deleting line. or group of line. And also can you  please tell me how to get number of current line where cursor is?

Comment: to delete a line, take your cursor on that line and press `dd`. to delete two lines press `2dd` so on. TO get the line numbers, `ESC + :set nu`, this will display the line numbers.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: is it possible to undu the change?

Comment: To undo, `ESC + :u`. press `u` multiple times to undo multiple changes.